On the continuity of the function $f(x)=\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos t}{x^2+t^2}dt$.
Let $F(x)=\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos t}{x^2+t^2}dt$. Then which of the following are correct?

$f$ is bounded on $\mathbb R$

$f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$

$f$ is not defined everywhere on $\mathbb R$

$f$ is not continuous on $\mathbb R$


Here is Let $f(x)=\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos t}{x^2+t^2}dt$. Then which of the following are correct? one of the solutions. I am unable to get the continuity of $F$ in the linked solution. I tried as follows.
We are given the function:
$$
F(x) = \int_1^\infty \frac{\cos(t)}{x^2 + t^2} \, dt,
$$
and we need to show that $F(x)$ is continuous on $ \mathbb{R} $.
Step 1: Pointwise Convergence
Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. We need to show that:
$$
\lim_{x \to x_0} F(x) = F(x_0).
$$
This means we aim to demonstrate:
$$
\lim_{x \to x_0} \int_1^\infty \frac{\cos(t)}{x^2 + t^2} \, dt = \int_1^\infty \frac{\cos(t)}{x_0^2 + t^2} \, dt.
$$
Step 2: Dominating Function
Next, we seek a dominating function that does not depend on $x $. Observe that:
$$
\left| \frac{\cos(t)}{x^2 + t^2} \right| \leq \frac{1}{t^2}.
$$
This holds for all $ x \in \mathbb{R} $ and $ t \geq 1 $. The function $\frac{1}{t^2} $ is integrable over $ [1, \infty) $, since:
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t^2} \, dt = 1.
$$
Thus, we can take $g(t) = \frac{1}{t^2} $ as the dominating function.
Step 3: Apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem
By the Dominated Convergence Theorem (DCT), we can interchange the limit and the integral. Hence, we have:
$$
\lim_{x \to x_0} F(x) = \lim_{x \to x_0} \int_1^\infty \frac{\cos(t)}{x^2 + t^2} \, dt = \int_1^\infty \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{\cos(t)}{x^2 + t^2} \, dt = F(x_0).
$$
Thus $F$ is continuous.
Please verify that am I correct? Thank you.

Is it $\cos t$ or $\cos x$ in the integral?

@GiuseppeNegro its cos(t).

@GiuseppeNegro I edited it. Thank you.

Yes, it's correct, but there's a little remark to do.
The DCT in its main form talks about sequences, so we have to understand why it's fine to use it in this context. The usual motivation is the following: since the domain is $\mathbb R$, which is first countable, the continuity is equivalent to the sequential continuity, which clearly follows from the usual DCT.

Your answer parallels the linked answer which looks at it from the perspective of an improper Riemann integral.  Either DCT or  the Weierstrass test implying uniform convergence lets you conclude that
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \int_1^\infty \frac{\cos(t)}{x^2 + t^2} \, dt = \int_1^\infty \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{\cos(t)}{x^2 + t^2} \, dt$$
You  also need the continuity of the integrand to justifty that
$$\int_1^\infty \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{\cos(t)}{x^2 + t^2} \, dt= \int_1^\infty  \frac{\cos(t)}{x_0^2 + t^2} \, dt= F(x_0)$$
The continuity of the integrand was used directly in the linked answer to show that the integral over a bounded interval is continuous with respect to the parameter.
